# Use of unassigned local variable c# using OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I am having a problem and have been banging my head aginst a wall... I keep getting a "Use of unassigned local variable" when I call "dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();" it says the Use of unassigned local variable 'dbCommand'. Would someone please take a look at this and tell me where and what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advanced.

```
    public void computerList()
    {
        //Create SQL strings
        string sql = "SELECT Computers FROM [Sheet1$]";

        //Create the instances
        OleDbConnection dbConnection;
        OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter;
        OleDbCommand dbCommand;
        OleDbDataReader dbReader; 
        DataTable dataTable;

        //Call the instance
        dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Y:\\\\serverName\\Share\\document.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'");
        dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, dbConnection);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        dbConnection.Open();
        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dbReader.Read())
        {
            int iRow = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            //MessageBox.Show("Count " + iRow.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(dbReader.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < iRow; i++)
            {
                int loopID = i;
                string rowData = dataTable.TableName;
                MessageBox.Show("Count" + loopID);
                MessageBox.Show(dbReader.GetString(iRow));
            }

        }
        //Close Connections 
        dbReader.Close();
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Of course you get that error.  You never initialize `dbCommand`.

Comment: When in doubt, trust that the compiler error really *is* correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand (sql , dbConnection)
```

you are initializing `dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, dbConnection);`

instead..

also You should use the using Statements for the Dispose and close of the connections and readers instead of

```
dbReader.Close();
dbConnection.Close();
```

I would rewrite it like this...

```
public void computerList()
    {
        //Create SQL strings
        string sql = "SELECT Computers FROM [Sheet1$]";       

        using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Y:\\\\serverName\\Share\\document.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"))
        {
           //dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, dbConnection); //You dont need it
           //dataTable = new DataTable(); //don't need it
           dbConnection.Open();
           using(OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand (sql , dbConnection))
           {
              using(OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
              {
                   while (dbReader.Read())
                   {
                      //int iRow = dataTable.Rows.Count; //always zero you never used the datable
                      //MessageBox.Show("Count " + iRow.ToString());
                      //MessageBox.Show(dbReader.ToString());
                      for (int i = 0; i < dbReader.FieldCount; i++)
                      {
                          //int loopID = i; //dont need it
                          //string rowData = dataTable.TableName; //Dont need it
                          MessageBox.Show("Count" + i);
                          MessageBox.Show(dbReader.GetString(i));
                       }

                    }
               } //reader closed and disposed          
           }//command disposed
        } //connection closed and disposed
  }
```

Comment: If you feel good wit the answer, and you think is the best answer of all, dont forget to mark it as the accepted one. Good to know that it helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise dbCommand

```
//Call the instance
dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Y:\\\\serverName\\Share\\document.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'");
dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", dbConnection);
dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, dbConnection);
dataTable = new DataTable();
dbConnection.Open();
dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.71).aspx - Says you don't do that. It says you call the OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader.

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 The document is referring to the dbReader, which gets created by the `dbCommand.ExecuteReader()` function.  Your dataTable is empty, by the way.